# Two types of jquery ui referencing gets different results

Tags: css, jquery-ui, reference

If I add jquery ui reference as

```
<script src="/_Docs/_Altyapi/JqueryUi/jquery-ui.1.8.21.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then tagit editor works fine(just under tag editor input), like:

[image]

But, if I use references like

```
<script src="/_Docs/_Altyapi/JqueryUi/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_Docs/_Altyapi/JqueryUi/ui/jquery.ui.widget.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_Docs/_Altyapi/JqueryUi/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then, it doesn't work(as can be seen in photo2, custom autocomplete is at the top of page), like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the **position** JS file as well to get autocomplete to work. Probably:

```
<script src="/_Docs/_Altyapi/JqueryUi/ui/jquery.ui.position.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

For future reference, you can always go to the [widget's documentation page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) under **overview** and you'll see the dependencies for the widget.